# REST API cache control for shared cache on server?

Tags: rest, api, caching, cache-control

I would like to implement some caching on my REST API server so that clients can get faster responses from cached data that is shared among them.

However, I would still like to give clients the option of getting fresh data if they prefer it.

Most examples of the HTTP cache headers I have seen assume that the data is being cached locally on the client, but I will be storing it on my server in Redis.

What is the preferred method to expose cache control functionality to clients when the cache is server-side and shared?

Thank you.

Comment: Which cache headers "assume that the data is being cached locally"?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I meant articles/tutorials about HTTP cache headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

> Cache-Control: max-age=
>   Cache-Control: max-stale[=]
>   Cache-Control: min-fresh=
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-store
>   Cache-Control: no-transform
>   Cache-Control: only-if-cached

Comment: If-None-Match / ETag might be another thing to look at